# HTTP Authorization Header - Bearer token security

Tags: security, http, authentication, authorization, bearer-token

I'm building an API which will be consumed from both web and mobile platforms.

I would like some help and pieces of advice to `improve my bearer token authorization`.

#### Authentication

The current authentication is pretty simple. I will presume that the sent credentials are correct:

- Sending Email and password to API endpoint
- Storing user token with expiration date
- Replying client with user authorization token

#### Authorization

Then, any other action authorization consists in:

- Sending Authorization Bearer "token" header
- Deciding if the token owner is allowed to do the action
- Completing the operation

#### Concern

My concern is that **if anyone just review the request headers, the bearer token could easily be discovered**. That would allow the user to do any harmful request from any rest client.

Most of the requests that could be done intentionally bad, are completely valid from the application context. So, it wouldn't be easy to filter them out by request parameters.

#### Possible fix

I've been thinking about the possibility to **send on headers** :

- User authorization token
- Sent date or any other parameter
- Hash (token, other parameter)

On server, I would compare each parameter individually and then the encrypted hash.

So, if someone is sending the same hash with a different date, it could easily be detected as an intruder.

---

Do you have any other suggestion to make the communication more secure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution you are considering with the date and hash does not add any security against a basic adversary.  The expiry of tokens should be managed on the server side in the database.

The Oauth 2 threat model tells you how to protect your tokens in [section 4.6.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819#section-4.6.1).

Comment: The token lifetime and client's identifier are already covered. Following that instructions, should enabling SSL encryption be fair enough?

Comment: You absolutely, positively need TLS (SSL).  You cannot do anything securely without it.

Answer (score 0):

A Token which is visible on the network must have the ip and user agent(in case of website) encrypted in it. This way even if someone has your token they can't send it from any other means apart from the same ip and the browser.

Comment: I don't think that would be useful. I'm trying to avoid attacks from any source, in that case the ip would still be allowed to do requests.